# Angular | Проверка изменений данных на сервере

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi

Делаю FullStack angular, ASP.NET Web Api приложение, на нём страница заказа, у заказа есть состояние : принят/собирается и т.д., соответственно оно может меняться. Есть технологии (которые более эффективные чем interval с запросом), которые позволяют постоянно проверять изменения на сервере, и обновлять его у клиента.

Comment: Например [long polling](https://learn.javascript.ru/long-polling). Это самый простой вариант из существующих способов получать обновления с сервера.

Comment: Веб-сокеты. И в сторону SignalR гляньте!